# Configure mySQL for new Application when mySQL is already installed and configured by another Application

Tags: mysql

I have an Inventory Software which uses mySQL as back end. I have tested it in my computer and is working perfectly.

When I install my software in a computer I have to do the following steps:

1. Install mySQL server
2. Assign username as 'root' and password as 'root'
3. Create a database named 'dbInventory'
   Then my software will connect to the database 'dbInventory' through localhost, user 'root' and password 'root' and creates all tables required for the software.

Now the problem is, when I tried to install my software on one of my client's computer, there was already another Accounting software (provided by some other Vendor) installed which also uses mySQL as back end.
So, my installation steps 1 and 2 are already done. So I am not able to perform step 3 without username and password from step 2.

Without username and password is it possible to create database 'dbInventory'?

Even if it is possible, my Software still needs username and password to connect to the database.

If I uninstall mySQL and install it again, I may be able to perform all my 3 steps. Still the second software (Accounting Software from another vendor) may not work because their username and password may be different.

Please give me suggestions to overcome this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to get/ reset root password for mysql as you have system access and then do all working on mysql server.

Follow the steps below:

MySQL stores usernames and passwords in the user table inside the MySQL database. You can directly update a password using the following method to update or change passwords:

1) Login to the MySQL server, type the following command at the shell prompt:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

2) Use the mysql database (type commands at the mysql> prompt):

```
mysql> use mysql;
```

3) Change password for a user:

```
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("newpass") where User='ENTER-USER-NAME-HERE';
```

4) Reload privileges:

```
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

You can get root password from user table before update using select query.

Comment: try this method first

Comment: mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: use this instead, stop mysql and start with this commnand `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

Comment: Then try with this `mysql -u root` and further as above

Comment: mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143563/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-gladis).